# "sforce.one.navigateToURL" does not navigate to Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, salesforce1-app, navigation, sforce

I have got a special problem using the "sforce.one.navigateToURL" command in a visualforce page.

I am using the following code snippet to redirect a user from a visualforce Page to a Lightning Component. Unfortunaetly this does not work anymore in the Salesforce1 App since the Winter 2018 Release. I do get the error message:

"You cant view this page, either beause you dont have permission or because the page isnt supported on mobile devices."

Nevertheless everything works fine in Browser on Mobile and Desktop.

```
function showMobilePage(){
        //redirect to mobile page; URL Hacking is necessary as salesforce doesent provide a navigation container for this use case
        var url = window.location.href;
        var urlParameter;
        var id;

        /&id=([^&]+)/.exec(url) && (id = /id=([^&]+)/.exec(url)[1]);
        //show create page, to edit a Record
        urlParameter = "{\"componentDef\" : \"c:lightningComp\" " +
                ", \"attributes\" : {" +
                "\"recordId\" : \""+ id + "\" }}"; 

        //use base64 encoding to generate url
        encodedURL = encodeStringBase64(urlParameter);
        sforce.one.navigateToURL('/one/one.app#' + encodedURL , true); 
    };

function encodeStringBase64(inputString){
    console.log(inputString);
    // Create Base64 Object
    var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}}
    // Encode the String
    return Base64.encode(inputString);
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. :)